# Carousel/slideshow left and right control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have slide show for my django. I am trying to put ".prev-btn" on left side vertically in the middle and ".next-btn" on the right side vertically in the middle. I tried `position:absolute, right: 10px;`but this wouldnt have any effect on the buttons. So i am thinking, if maybe you could help me. Here is working image display with .prev-btn and .next-btn not in right position:
https://jsfiddle.net/jozv4o29/3/
Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just added the below code and it works fine. You can absolutely position your buttons for prev and next navigation. And then translate it to shift by 50%. Just to make sure that it is exactly at the center.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jozv4o29/5/)

```
.prev-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    translate: transformY(-50%)
}
.prev-btn {
  left: 0;
}
.next-btn {
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to position arrows accordingly see below code

```
.prev-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
}
.prev-btn {
    left: 0;
}

.next-btn {
    right: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jozv4o29/4/